# Refactor the loop to merge one property when other properties are identical in ASP.net MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a dataset that currently produces an output as follows:

**Code:**
Part 1: The View -

```
@foreach (var dt in Model.PlaceList) {
    <tr class="Gap">
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h3>@dt.PlaceName</h3><br />
                <span>@dt.OpenTimings</span><br />
                <span>@dt.Slot</span><br />
                <span>@dt.ActivityName</span><br />
                <span>@dt.Address</span><br />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Part 2: Data Retrieval from DB

```
var gPlaceList = (from l in _appdb.GetPlaceDetails
    select new GetListPlaces {
        PlaceName = l.PlaceName,
        OpenTimings = l.OpenTimings,
        Slot = l.Slot,
        Activity = l.Activity,
        Address = l.Address
    }).ToList();
```

Part 3: Data structure used to populate the entries

```
public partial class GetListPlaces {
    public string PlaceName { get; set; }
    public string OpenTimings { get; set; }
    public string Slot { get; set; }
    public string Activity { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

When looking at the result of output for one Place, we get groups of data that looke like so:

**Current Output:**

> ```
> Place Name
> Open Timings
> Slot1
> Activity
> Address
>
> Place Name
> Open Timings
> Slot2
> Activity
> Address 
>
> Place Name
> Open Timings
> Slot3
> Activity
> Address
>
> Place Name
> Open Timings
> Slot4
> Activity
> Address
>
> Place Name
> Open Timings
> Slot5
> Activity
> Address
> ```

We want to merge the result to look like this, for all results where the other 4 columns match.

**Expected Output:**

> ```
> Place Name
> Open Timings
> Slot1, Slot2, Slot3, Slot4, Slot5
> Activity
> Address
> ```

The data here is just a sample. the real output in our website has thousands of results and merging the data like this will help us in reducing the display area as well as reduce duplication of data.

Comment: Can you share the code of populating the model and data retrieval? Also sharing some sample data with expected output would be helpful.

Comment: I will add it in some time. this is an over simplified version and needs some modification.

Comment: Accurate detail in question! check the answer(s) below. Let us know if it does not help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group your data and show it comma separated using string extension method 'Join'

```
@foreach (var dt in Model.PlaceList.GroupBy(x=> new { x.PlaceName, x.OpenTimings, x.ActivityName, x.Address }))
{
    <tr class="Gap">
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h3>@dt.Key.PlaceName</h3><br />
                <span>@dt.Key.OpenTimings</span><br />
                <span>@string.Join(",", dt.ToList().Select(x=>x.SlotNo))</span><br />
                <span>@dt.Key.ActivityName</span><br />
                <span>@dt.Key.Address</span><br />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tejas, i plugged in your answer and everything fell smoothly into place. It took me this long to verify the result of all entries and they are working exactly as needed. Thank you once again.

Comment: anytime mate..!

Answer (score 2):

Use grouping! Just group records by the values that you expect to be same, and use Select to form a new record:

```
Model.PlaceList
     .GroupBy(x => {x.PlaceName, x.OpenTimings, x.ActivityName, x.Address})
     .Select(group => new
        {
            PlaceName = group.Key.PlaceName,
            OpenTimings = group.Key.OpenTimings,
            ...,
            Slots = String.Join(", ", group.Select(x => x.SlotNo))
        })
```

Now one record will contain exactly the kind information you needed, and you can loop over the results of this query to output the view.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, we perform some additional calculation from the result retrieved from our View Model. Really appreciate your help and look forward to using this solution very soon. Thank you.